# New content available at the Safe House?

Tags: hitman-absolution

I just logged in to Hitman: Absolution and got a message saying "New content downloaded from server.  You can find it at the Safe House."

I've only played the single player campaign so far, I haven't gotten into Contracts mode.

**What's the Safe House and where do I find it?**

Comment: It's simply a screen where you get to pick a weapon and a disguise in Contracts mode. I think you should've probably checked the Contracts mode before posting the question. No offence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a screen where you get to pick a weapon and a disguise in Contracts mode. (I should've probably checked the Contracts mode before posting the question.) Thanks deutchZuid!